# Are increasingly common earthquakes the result of demolishing illegal immigrant tunnels?

Tags: united-states

> Earthquakes are becoming increasingly common, but they aren't naturally occurring. Some part of the military is acting by orders of President Trump to demolish the many underground tunnels all across the country used for illegal immigration, sex trafficking, transportation of illicit goods, etc. For example, [the recent "puzzling" earthquakes in South Carolina](https://abcnews.go.com/Technology/wireStory/experts-puzzled-continuing-south-carolina-earthquakes-82090417) were caused by explosions destroying these tunnels.

Someone who I would like to trust recently told me this theory verbally. They insisted that they got it from "reputable news source" Rumble but couldn't point me to the exact article or video as it was likely "taken down by the government because they don't want the people to know what's going on." The closest thing I found was a [video](https://rumble.com/vo4zzz-earthquakes-in-la-palma-are-happening-in-a-pattern-that-is-not-natural.-ds-.html) by Michael Jaco. This is the first I've heard of him, but I noticed that his podcast featured David Icke who I am well aware is an infamous conspiracy theorist. Is there any truth at all behind this theory, or is it just made-up nonsense?

Comment: South Carolina seems like a strange place for those types of tunnels and the military destroying them. It might make sense if it was a state that bordered another country on the land.

Comment: Not to mention that any such detonations in South Carolina can't be "on the order of President Trump" because Trump hasn't been the president for a year now.

Comment: @JoeW I thought the same thing, but "why else would there be unusual earthquakes in South Carolina?"

Comment: @F1Krazy they implied that the orders were given while he was still in office and are still being carried out now. Believe me, I laughed when they told me, but they insisted that I "do my own research." If the conclusion is in fact that this is nonsense and I need to stop trusting their opinion on things, then so be it. I just wanted to know if there was any merit to the claims that I had been unable to find on my own.

Comment: Strangely, when I tried to access rumble.com it was blocked, not by my AV, but by my UK network provider. That's never happened with any other site. Anyway, Rumble is a Canadian site based in Toronto, so how could the story have been "taken down by the [US] government".

Comment: @WeatherVane obviously because the government doesn't want you to know the truth /s

Comment: I didn't ask Why but How? It's "common knowledge" that everything we are told is  a lie [sarcasm].

Comment: Well in some areas they are having increased earthquakes and they think the know the reason for it. https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/does-fracking-cause-earthquakes

Comment: Closest I have found to a notable claim: https://www.wired.com/2012/03/haiti-quakes/

Answer (score 9):

No, because ordinary explosions do not cause significant earthquakes, and the earthquakes are occurring in places and at depths where tunnels are almost impossible to have been dug.

First, we have extensive, public information about seismic activity across the United States, published by the U.S. Geological Survey and other non-federal entities. The U.S. is covered by a network of thousands of seismographs, including more than 400 through the [USArray program](http://www.usarray.org/), providing a rich set of data for any seismic activity within the country.

> "Each USArray station includes the instrumentation necessary to
> continuously sense, record, and transmit ground motions from a wide
> range of seismic sources, including local and distant earthquakes,
> artificial explosions, volcanic eruptions, and other natural and
> human-induced activities."

Each type of seismic activity generates a distinct fingerprint. For example, we can tell the difference between a nuclear explosion and a non-nuclear explosion of equivalent size by the relative abruptness of a point-source blast compared to a volume of explosives. There's a difference between strike-slip activity on a deep fault and a series of demolition blasts and the subsequent collapsing rock of tunnels.

Also, [according to the U.S. Geological Survey](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/can-we-use-explosives-cause-small-earthquakes-order-prevent-having-large-ones), "even huge amounts of explosive almost never cause even small earthquakes, and it would take hundreds and thousands of small earthquakes to equal a large one, even if it could be done."

In the particular case of South Carolina, some of the quakes in the recent series are occurring from 500 meters to 5 kilometers deep about 1,200 miles from the Mexican border. The deepest smuggling tunnel between the United States and Mexico went to only 27 meters, and most cross-border tunnels are less than 10 meters deep, in part due to the high groundwater table. [The typical groundwater table for Kershaw County, South Carolina, where Elgin is located, is about 53 feet, or 16 meters, according to the USGS](https://waterdata.usgs.gov/sc/nwis/uv/?site_no=342440080443900&PARAmeter_cd=72019).

It is unlikely that any smuggling tunnels being demolished would be below the groundwater table at the depths of the detected earthquakes, and unlikely that any such demolitions would cause earthquakes.